# How to set permission list item in custom list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, web-part, visual-web-part

I create a web part.this web part is using "add a item". it was completed.

My problem: I want to create a web part which is having below ex.

Ex:
I login on my account-> add a item.
B person login b account -> add a item
C person login c account -> add a item

I want :
I only see my files all. If I login on my account
B only see b files all. If B login on b account.
...
Of course, I want to create a new web part for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set item level permission so that each user get permission to items created by them.

In your code once item is created you can use below code to set item level permission.

Code being referred from [link](http://www.thespgeek.com/2011/08/assigning-sharepoint-list-item-level.html)

Assumption:

1. You have SPListItem object in your hand
2. You have a valid SPUser in your hand

First call the below method and pass the SPListItem as the input parameter:

```
private static void RemoveAllPermissions(SPListItem CurrentlistItem)
        {
            //The below function Breaks the role assignment inheritance for the list and gives the current list its own copy of the role assignments
            CurrentlistItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
            //Get the list of Role Assignments to list item and remove one by one.
            SPRoleAssignmentCollection SPRoleAssColn = CurrentlistItem.RoleAssignments;
            for (int i = SPRoleAssColn.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                SPRoleAssColn.Remove(i);
            }
        }
```

Next call the below method and pass the desired parameters:

```
private static void GrantPermission(SPListItem CurrentListItem, SPWeb oSPWeb, SPRoleType SPRoleType, SPPrincipal SPPrincipal)
        {
            try
            {
                //Create one Role Definition i.e Full Controls, Contribute rights or Read rights etc.
                SPRoleDefinition oSPRoleDefinition = oSPWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType);
                //Create one Role Assignment for the specified SP user or group.
                SPRoleAssignment oSPRoleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(SPPrincipal);
                //Bind the role definition to the role assignment object created for the user or group.
                oSPRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(oSPRoleDefinition);
                //Add it to the specified list item.
                CurrentListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(oSPRoleAssignment);
                //update the list item so that specified user assignment will have the access.
                CurrentListItem.Update();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Error in UAR Initiation Workflow", "GrantPermission() : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

For your easy reference I am including the code block from where I used to call these functions:

```
if (validUsername)
                            {
                                if (rdr["Manager Logon"] != null)
                                {
                                    SPUser CurrentUser = mySite.EnsureUser(rdr["Manager Logon"].ToString());
                                    RemoveAllPermissions(item);
                                    GrantPermission(item, mySite, SPRoleType.Contributor, CurrentUser);
                                    SPGroup oGroup = mySite.SiteGroups["UARAdministrators"];
                                    GrantPermission(item, mySite, SPRoleType.Administrator, oGroup);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Admin need to resolve this issue in the list
                                RemoveAllPermissions(item);
                                SPGroup oGroup = mySite.SiteGroups["UARAdministrators"];
                                GrantPermission(item, mySite, SPRoleType.Administrator, oGroup);
                            }
```

Comment: For your easy reference I am including the code block from where I used to call these functions:
I dont' understant. Where do I add this code ?

Comment: That code block needs to be used after code where item is getting added..... or simply call above 2 functions based on your logic, you can ignore that code block..that code block was just to give you idea on how to use above functions...